# htaccess file for http to https redirection does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem and can't understand wht it does not work...

- I have a website in [www.example.com/FOLDER](http://www.example.com/FOLDER)
- I try to create a http to https htaccess file (of course my server supports it)
- So i create an .htaccess file in the FOLDER subir as so:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On  
>  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
>  RewriteRule FOLDER/(.*) https://www.example.com/FOLDER/$1 [R,L]
> ```

but it does not work: if I browse to http://www.example.com/FOLDER/index.php, it remains in http, it is not redirected to https://...

I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} FOLDER 
RewriteRule FOLDER/(.*) https://www.example.com/FOLDER/$1 [R,L]
```

but still no luck...

If i try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/FOLDER/$1 [R,L]
```

the server replies error: too many redirects... (which I dont understand since the redirect should go in https and so the condition should not apply the 2nd time...)

If I do all that stuff in an .htaccess file in the root directory I still have the same problems...

BUT, if I do

http://www.example.com/FOLDER/SUBFOLDER

then it works and sends me to

https://www.example.com/FOLDER/SUBFOLDER

What am I missing??

---

Additional data requested:

SERVER:

```
[PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR] => :/web/htdocs/www.example.com/php.d
    [PORTID] => 10018
    [DOMAINNAME] => www.example.com
    [APACHE_MAX_SPARE] => 3
    [WORKERS] => 35
    [APACHE_THREADS] => 5
    [PM_MAX_CHILDREN] => 40
    [SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME] => php-fpm
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [PM_MAX_REQUESTS] => 1000
    [HOME] => /root
    [PM_PROCESS_IDLE_TIMEOUT] => 60s
    [LANG] => en_US.utf8
    [TERM] => xterm
    [SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL] => unix:///var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock
    [APACHE_SERVER_LIMITS] => 8
    [SHLVL] => 0
    [SUPERVISOR_ENABLED] => 1
    [GROUPNAME] => 18729849
    [PM] => dynamic
    [USERNAME] => 18729849
    [APACHE_MIN_SPARE] => 1
    [SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME] => php-fpm
    [MAINDOMAINNAME] => www.example.com
    [APACHE_MAX_WORKERS] => 40
    [HOSTNAME] => webxc250s02.ad.xxxx.xx
    [APACHE_START_SERVERS] => 1
    [PWD] => /
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /ser.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /ser.php
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 10410
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/ser.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => postmaster@www.example.com
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => nnn
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_ADDR] => nnn
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.example.com
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] =>      
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6,pt;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4,de;q=0.3,es;q=0.2
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM] => "Windows"
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE] => ?0
    [HTTP_SEC_CH_UA] => " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
    [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => none
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 443
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => nnn
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com
    [proxy-nokeepalive] => 1
    [HTTPS] => on
    [UNIQUE_ID] => xxx
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /ser.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1638222363.152
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1638222363
```

---

.htaccess in the root

```
Options +Indexes  

ErrorDocument 401 default

RewriteEngine On
   
RewriteRule ^$  https://www.example.com/index.php [QSA,L,R=301]
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [QSA,L]
   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L] 
  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} nologin
RewriteRule ^(.*)/nologin$ https://www.example.com/$1?nologin [QSA,L,R]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login$ https://www.example.com/$1?login [QSA,L,R]
  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ - [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ico$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ico$ - [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt$ - [L]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ - [L]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ - [L]    
 
RewriteRule ^home$ my.php?layout= [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home/$ my.php?layout= [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)$ my.php?layout=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*/)$ my.php?layout=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)/(.*)$ my.php?layout=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ my.php?e3=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ my.php?e3=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ my.php?e3=$1&layout=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ my.php?e3=$1&layout=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ my.php?e3=$1&layout=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) we.php?layout=default [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
```

Comment: Replace `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http`

Comment: Still doesn work...

Comment: How is the SSL cert implemented? The use of the `HTTPS` server variable assumes the SSL cert is managed by your application server. But if you are using a proxy/CDN/load balancer then this may not work, since the connection from the proxy to your application server is often over HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: i'm on a standard provider, I have other sites on the same domain and redirect rules (different from this one) do work...

Comment: "i'm on a standard provider" - What does that mean? Shared hosting providers often implement _transparent_ caching proxies (whether you are aware of this or not). Since you are using PHP you can dump the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal and add this to your question. Also include the complete contents of your root and any subdirectory `.htaccess` files. Incidentally, your first two rule blocks won't do anything at all if placed in the `/FOLDER/.htaccess` file. Bear in mind that mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

Comment: I added info you requested in the post, thanks.

Comment: Is the website in `/FOLDER/` separate from the website in the document root? Does `/FOLDER/.htaccess` currently exist? Do you want everything to be redirect to HTTPS, or just `/FOLDER/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
> [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 443
> [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => nnn
> :
> [HTTPS] => on
> ```

You are evidently behind a proxy server of some kind. It is unclear here whether `HTTPS` is the Apache server variable or an environment variable of the same name, set by your system. I assume the later, since you were getting a redirect-loop when testing against `%{HTTPS} off` in Apache.

If you are wanting to apply this only to the `/FOLDER/` subdirectory then create a `/FOLDER/.htaccess` file and try the following:

```
# /FOLDER/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This tests the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header which is set by an intermediary proxy. This rule should *only* be used if you are behind a proxy server (as appears to be the case), since this header could otherwise be faked.

This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect, so change `R` to `R=301` once you have confirmed this works as intended.

Note that mod_rewrite directives are not inherited (by default) so the mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are not processed.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much you made my day!!